# Mongoengine: how to recursively dereference a document json-serialise them?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

Having a `mongoengine` document that has a few `ReferenceFields`, how can be these recursively converted to JSON?

So far, I've tried:

1. `to_mongo()` but `ReferenceFields` were ignored.
2. `DeReference()(video._data)`, I get only the `repr()` of each referenced model:

```json
{
   'audience': 0,
   'channels': [],
   'created_date': datetime.datetime(2006, 1, 2, 12, 11, 3),
   'id': ObjectId('51af7076a2aa1c2179035e8e'),
   'images': {},
   'kind': u'VOD',
   'modified_date': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 5, 19, 39, 4, 327000),
   'parts': [
      [<Media: VOD 0x0>,
       <Media: VOD 0x0>,
       <Media: VOD 0x0>,
       <Media: VOD 0x0>]
    ],
   'provider': <Provider: TEST>,
   'published_date': datetime.datetime(2006, 1, 2, 12, 11, 3),
   'sources': [<Source: TEST>],
   'titles': {u'en-US': u'TEST', u'es-ES': u'PRUEBA', u'pt-BR': u'TESTE'}
}
```

Are `Media`, `Provider` and `Source` objects not being serialized as they are supposed to be or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the ReferenceField value you need to call `to_mongo()` on the reference field - not the parent document as that will just return the DBRef or ObjectId for the document.

So in your example - you have 3 reference fields: `provider`, `parts` and `sources` given a document instance called `my_doc` to get the dictionary values of the referenced documents do:

```
provider = my_doc.provider.to_mongo()
parts = [part.to_mongo() for part in my_doc.parts]
sources = [source.to_mongo() for source in my_doc.sources]
```

** side note

The schema shown seems highly relational and ReferenceFields cause in app joins (MongoEngine has to query internally and dereference for you).  This won't be performant at high levels of scale as to get all the parts of your document - you need to query once for the document itself, once for the provider, once for the parts and once for the sources - **4 queries** to retrieve one document.  For larger querysets without doing `queryset.select_related(2)` this means for **4x queryset count**.  Which may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Now is no out of the box way to fetch data from DBRef. But `to_mongo` dict conatins:

1. simple items like numbers, strings, datetimes, ids and etc.
2. DBRef items
3. list items
4. dict items

So you can iterate by lists and dicts and check DBRef types, after fetch and replace it with `to_mongo`. But you must check which references you need, how deep sub references you must fetch, how correct resolve self and recursive references.

For example look how mongo python driver convert python objects to itself format: [`bson.json_util._json_convert`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/json_util.py#L130).